# My computer can only connect to Google and WhatsApp's websites every morning on this specific WiFi connection; how can I fix this issue?

Tags: wireless-networking, google-chrome, internet-connection

Every morning, when my laptop is connected with my school's WiFi connection, it becomes unable to access any websites except for *[www.google.com](http://www.google.com)* and *web.whatsapp.com*. Every other site times out, until around 10am. I know that it is my laptop's issue because my phone and others' devices are able to access the web freely. What's wrong and how can I fix it? This issue persists on all browsers and apps that require an internet connection.

Answer (score 1):

I found a fix for this issue, even though I'm not sure what was causing it in the first place, nor do I know why this issue only persisted on my school's WiFi network. I came across this unexpected fix while messing with chrome URLs because I was bored while the abovementioned issue happened to me. Hence, it's pretty explanatory that you need Google Chrome to fix this issue.

*All you have to do*: access [chrome://net-internals/#proxy](http://chrome://net-internals/#proxy) and click the **Clear bad proxies** button. This should fix the issue, and I hope it helps you if you're faced with this. If the issue re-surfaces, you can try clicking the **Re-apply settings** button.

Comment: sounds like your school is pushing a proxy config to chrome, that only works when you are on the school wifi. if you connect to another wifi, the proxy will not be found and timeout. clearing the proxy restores your connection, but then you go through it all over again the next day. sound about right?